# Find my iPhone shows family members' devices

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone

I am trying to understand why are these devices showing when I log into Find my iPhone.

I checked each device (belongs to family members) and each is logged into their own iClouds with their own login info.

Turning off Find my iPhone on their device[s] stops it from showing up on the map, and turning it on adds it back.

[image]

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Is family sharing involved?  I just logged into find my iPhone for the first time in a long while, I see that as organizer I can see my families devices.

Answer (score 3):

That’s due to Family Sharing, indicated by the “…’s Devices” header on each section. If you’re an adult member of Family Sharing, you see all the family devices on Find My iPhone.

Comment: It looks like a child member can see other devices in the family as well. Just asked a question specifically about that: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388259/how-to-prevent-child-from-using-find-my-to-interact-with-parents-device