# How to prevent child from using Find My to interact with parent's device?

Tags: family-sharing, children, find-my

Both me and my child are members of one Family, with Family Sharing turned on. We use different Apple IDs. When my child opens "Find My" app, my devices are listed there as well.

How do I prevent my devices from showing up on that list?

The only option I have found is that I can turn off Location Sharing. But my child can still for example use "Play Sound" to remotely play a sound on my device.

I know that I can turn off "Find My" for any of my particular devices completely, but that would also prevent me from finding this device using my iCloud account, so I don't want to do that.

Alternatively, perhaps there's a way to block "Find My" on child's device completely?

Comment: on you iPhone under your AppleID -> Family Sharing -> Location sharing you can toggle the feature if you need to remove it. However under the Find My tab in your Apple ID, turning off share  my location, with Find My iPhone still enabled will allow your Apple Account to still find your device via icloud.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement parental controls on their device for your OS. Now it’s wrapped into Screen Time.

I consider it a bug you can’t specify zero minutes to block an app, please file a bug with apple to hide it entirely if you agree. For now, we get one minute of window a day if we use this mechanism to “block” the Find My app.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304

Sadly, parenting them is the only way if they want to ignore the one minute warning and use the app once a day.

Comment: If you look closely at the link you shared you can see that "Find My" is not on the list of the apps you can restrict, unfortunately. But thanks to your comment I checked in "App Limits" and "Find My" made it there, finally (I'm pretty sure it wasn't included a couple of OS version ago). Still, the best you can do with it is to restrict "Find My" usage to 1 minute per day. Better than nothing :-)

Comment: Looks like apple still wants you to share all or none in terms of location as a family @KrzysztofJelski   I’ll edit your details in the body. Did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here, but FWIW, if you go to:

*Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> Share My Location*

there is a toggle button called Share my Location which is described as

> Share your location with family and friends in Messages and Find My, make personal requests using Siri on HomePod and use automations in the Home app.

If you turn this off, then I think no-one (other than you) should be able to locate your devices.

Comment: I think they want to keep the location sharing active for everyone but only let the “adult” accounts send audible pings to devices regardless of the “location” being blocked temporarily ?

Comment: Maybe, but the question asks how "to prevent child from using Find My to interact with parent's device?". This will do that. They might not want to do this, but I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted.